# PHP LDAP Get user details of member which is a member of a group

Tags: php, active-directory, ldap

I'm trying to create a PHP script that will return some details of each member that is part of a specific group in our Active Directory.

I have no problem connecting and display the names (CN) of the group members but when it comes to displaying details such as telephone, email and username I'm stuck.

Here's my code I'm trying with. Can anyone see what I'm doing wrong?

```
<?php
$ldap_server = "AD_Server.domain.pri:389";
$auth_user = "user@domain.pri";
$auth_pass = "password";

$base_dn = "OU=IM Groups,OU=GLOBAL,DC=domain,DC=pri";
$filter = "(&(objectCategory=user)(memberOf=IM-ALL_USERS))";

// connect to server
if (!($connect=@ldap_connect($ldap_server))) {
     die("Could not connect to ldap server");
}

// bind to server
if (!($bind = ldap_bind($connect, $auth_user, $auth_pass))) {
     die("Unable to bind to server");
}

// search active directory
if (!($search = ldap_search($connect, $base_dn, $filter))) {
     die("Unable to search ldap server");
}

$number_returned = ldap_count_entries($connect,$search);
$info = ldap_get_entries($connect, $search);

echo "The number of entries returned is ". $number_returned."<p>";

for ($i=0; $i<$info["count"]; $i++) {
   echo "Name is: ". $info[$i]["givenname"][0]."<br>";
   echo "Display name is: ". $info[$i]["displayname"][0]."<br>";
   echo "Email is: ". $info[$i]["mail"][0]."<br>";
   echo "Telephone number is: ". $info[$i]["telephonenumber"][0]."<p>";
}
?>
```

Comment: Have you tried dumping out the `$info` array with print_r/vardump to see what all's in there?

Comment: The $info array just contains "Array ( [count] => 0 )" so it looks like the script isn't happy with the filter.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Worked it out using an excellent function created by [Sam J Levy](http://samjlevy.com/using-php-and-ldap-to-list-of-members-of-an-active-directory-group/).

Here's the final code that worked.

```
<?php

function explode_dn($dn, $with_attributes=0)
{
    $result = ldap_explode_dn($dn, $with_attributes);
    foreach($result as $key => $value) $result[$key] = preg_replace("/\\\([0-9A-Fa-f]{2})/e", "''.chr(hexdec('\\1')).''", $value);
    return $result;
}

function get_members($group,$user,$password) {
    $ldap_host = "LDAPSERVER";
    $ldap_dn = "OU=some_group,OU=some_group,DC=company,DC=com";
    $base_dn = "DC=company,DC=com";
    $ldap_usr_dom = "@company.com";
    $ldap = ldap_connect($ldap_host);

    ldap_set_option($ldap, LDAP_OPT_PROTOCOL_VERSION,3);
    ldap_set_option($ldap, LDAP_OPT_REFERRALS,0);

    ldap_bind($ldap, $user . $ldap_usr_dom, $password);
    $results = ldap_search($ldap,$ldap_dn, "cn=" . $group);
    $member_list = ldap_get_entries($ldap, $results);

    $dirty = 0;
    $group_member_details = array();

    foreach($member_list[0]['member'] as $member) {
        if($dirty == 0) {
            $dirty = 1;
        } else {
            $member_dn = explode_dn($member);
            $member_cn = str_replace("CN=","",$member_dn[0]);
            $member_search = ldap_search($ldap, $base_dn, "(CN=" . $member_cn . ")");
            $member_details = ldap_get_entries($ldap, $member_search);
            $group_member_details[] = array($member_details[0]['givenname'][0],$member_details[0]['sn'][0],$member_details[0]['telephonenumber'][0],$member_details[0]['othertelephone'][0]);
        }
    }
    ldap_close($ldap);
    return $group_member_details;
}

// Specify the group from where to get members and a username and password with rights to query it
$result = get_members("groupname","username","password");

// The following will create an XML file with the details from $group_member_details
$xml = simplexml_load_string("<?xml version='1.0'?>\n<AddressBook></AddressBook>");
$version = $xml->addChild('version', '1');

foreach($result as $e) {
    $contact = $xml->addChild('Contact');
    $contact->addChild('FirstName', $e[0]);
    $contact->addChild('LastName', $e[1]);
    $phone = $contact->addChild('Phone');
    if ($e[3] == '') {
                $phone->addChild('phonenumber', '0');
        } else {
                $phone->addChild('phonenumber', $e[3]);
        }
    $phone->addChild('accountindex', '0');
    $phone = $contact->addChild('Phone');
    if ($e[2] == '') {
        $phone->addChild('phonenumber', '0');
    } else {
        $phone->addChild('phonenumber', $e[2]);
    }
    $phone->addChild('accountindex', '1');
    $contact->addChild('Group', '0');
    $contact->addChild('PhotoUrl', 'empty');
}

$xml->asXML('phonebook.xml');

?>
```

Comment: Glad you found my function helpful, I noticed the link in your post is no longer working, it can be found at http://samjlevy.com/2011/02/using-php-and-ldap-to-list-of-members-of-an-active-directory-group/