# Equivalent of $_SERVER['REMOTE_USER'] for user groups

Tags: php, authentication, iis

I’m using Windows Authentication for access to a web site hosted on a Windows 2008R2 server with IIS 7.0 and URL Authorisation Rules for certain parts.  For this latter purpose I can add a user group for easier administration.

I would like to go a step further, and only show certain columns of a table, to specific users.  It works fine with this example of code – PHP, MySQL data:

```
if($_SERVER['REMOTE_USER']=='DUPONT') {echo "<td>" . $row['secret_garden'] . "</td>";}
```

Is there a way to do the same for a user group, rather than having to repeat above code several times?
I have tried to replace DUPONT in my example with the name of a user group, but it doesn’t work – I didn’t really expect so either, but gave it a try.
The user group is not a local user group, so I’m not administrating it myself.
Alternative idea: I’m checking if I can find a way to list the users and add them to a table so that I can use a variable in PHP to check if the user is in the table (MySQL).

Answer (score 0):

Most likely you will need to use PHP LDAP functions.

http://php.net/manual/en/book.ldap.php

This might be a good start as well.

[PHP LDAP Get user details of member which is a member of a group](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5327104/php-ldap-get-user-details-of-member-which-is-a-member-of-a-group)

Comment: Too advanced for me for now - will study your answer further when our support is back from holiday. While waiting I found a workaround using
   ** net group /domain your_group_name > Desktop\users.txt **
from command prompt and importing the data from a csv to MySQL.  It works but I will have to manually add new users until I work further on your suggestion.